# Setting up domains in a virtual machine running Apache

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, virtualhost, domain-server

I'm runnning Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS as host system. I created a virtual machine running Debian 7.2.0 and Apache 2.2 using VirtualBox 4.3.4. The network bridging between host and guest system was done with

> VBoxManage modifyvm "vm-www" --natpf1 "www,tcp,,80,,80"

The DNS has valid A record entry for the `domain.com`. I can access the apache root directory `/var/www` of the apache server over IP `100.100.100.100`. The forwarding of `domain.com` to the root directory is working.

my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
   DocumentRoot /var/www
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   Servername domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

However if I access `www.domain.com` I am still redirected to `/var/www` and NOT to `/var/www/domain`. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable the vhost_alias module in apache? You can enable it by running the command below as root:

```
a2enmod vhost_alias
```

Then restart apache with (again as root):

```
service apache2 restart
```